# Ratio of copper(II) ions to EDTA?

Tags: coordination-compounds, chemical-formula

> What is the ratio of copper(II) ions to EDTA in a $\ce{[Cu(EDTA)]^{2-}}$ complex?

I know that EDTA forms up to 6 coordinate bonds with the central atom, but is that what they are asking for with "ratio"?
According to [this website](http://www.chemthes.com/entity_datapage.php?id=3974), it seems that copper actually bonds with all 6 free electron pairs.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎ And, "homework" tag is for questions when you want a more "teacher" approach. It doesn't mean "homework" literally.

Comment: They're asking for the ration of **ions** i.e. for each $Cu^{2+}$ ion, how many $EDTA^{6-}$ are there.

Comment: So all that would be is 1:1, that's it?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @BinaryGeek EDTA has a maximum of a -4 charge. It can never reach -6.

Comment: @LDC3 Yeah, I wrote that by mistake. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of Cu to EDTA is the number of copper ions per EDTA ion. In this case there is one EDTA ion for every copper ion so the ratio is 1:1.

Copper bonds with six electron pairs on EDTA to form the complex shown below where the central metal species is copper(II):

[image]